Not able to understand S2-5’ in IPM motor datasheet?
I am working on an electric go-kart, the only specs of the motor I have are:
Motor type: IPM,
Operating voltage: 48V,
Nominal power: 6kw,
Peak Power: 8.5kw,
Peak motor torque: 42Nm,
Max rpm: 6700,
Peak efficiency: >90%
I have come up with a li-ion battery pack for this motor. Now to do that i'm using optimum lap software which requires the torque and rpm curve of the motor (which i don't have for my motor).
I was thinking of using data from a similar IPM motor to perform the analysis. While looking at this and other IPM motor data-sheets the the torque and power have multiple curves namely peak, S2-5’ and S2-30’ which i don't understand (Here is other data-sheet that has something similar).
Also is this approach correct, or should I do it some other way?
The major issue i'm facing is how many cells should I add in parallel for a run time of 30-40 mins, i'm planning to use Molicel P45-B cells (data-sheet).

I take it to be thermally limited torque and power for 60, 30, and 5 minutes, respectively.
(And few seconds: instant.)
S2 should refer to the IEC Duty Cycle rating short time.
